# If I try to re install or repair windows does it affect the dual boot(grub)?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have tried dual OS (Ubuntu 15.04) along with Windows 10. It was works correctly. Once I had change permissions in Ubuntu. then I tried to Resolve. But I Struggled. So I just Re Installing Ubuntu on windows. But Now Windows says Boot Failure.

1. Toshiba satellite
2. **Boot Mode**: CSM boot
3. **Error** : `File: Boot\Bcd
   Status:0*c000000e,
   Info: The Boot Configuration data for your pc is missing or contains error`
   Now I have USB Installation  media. With that media How Can I repair My disk. If I tries something, does it affect on Ubuntu or dual Boot something else? **I m Not ready to loose my data on both Ubuntu and Windows** 
   **If I try to re install or repair windows does it affect the dual boot(grub)**

Comment: Until trying anything else, can you use a live USB (with remanence) to  boot from it and save your data?

Comment: If I try to re install or repair windows does it affect the dual boot(grub)

Answer (score 0):

If you install windows then ubuntu grub will be replaced by windows boot loader. Although, Ubuntu/linux grub can detect any kind of OS windows boot loader can't unless windows. So, After installing windows you can not boot ubuntu immediately. You have to install grub which will show all of your operating system list at startup. You have to be careful in the time of installation of windows that, it doesn't affect the partitions where ubuntu is installed.

You may install grub from live USB mode using this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

If your ubuntu is 64 bit you have to install boot-repair from [there](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is a different boot option such as rEFInd. Google it and see if it meets your needs. I would have just put this in a comment, but rep is too low.